# How to plot AIC values when using the leaps package?

Tags: r, aic, stepwise-regression, validation, bic

Does anybody know how to plot all AIC values for different size models, when using the command `regsubsets` from the package `leaps`?

Assume you have the following variables:

```
treatment <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), levels = c(1, 2),labels = c("placebo", "treated"))

improved <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)),levels = c(1, 2, 3),labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))

numberofdrugs<-rpois(84, 5)+1

healthvalue<-rpois(84,5)
```

And now you want to select variables. Then you can use the following commands

```
require(leaps)
require(faraway)

d<-regsubsets(healthvalue~numberofdrugs*improved*treatment,x, nvmax=10)
rs<-summary(d)
plot(rs$bic, xlab="Parameter", ylab="BIC") #where is AIC (bic works)?
```

It works when using `rs$bic`, but why isn't there a way to use `rs$aic`? When looking at the help `?regsubsets`, it seems to be not available. Do I understand the help wrong? And if I don't understand it wrong, how can I plot the above code when using AIC?

Answer (score 6):

The relevant excerpt from the `regsubsets` help pages is the following:

> Since this function returns separate
>   best models of all sizes up to nvmax
>   and since different model selection
>   criteria such as AIC, BIC, CIC, DIC,
>   ... differ only in how models of
>   different sizes are compared, the
>   results do not depend on the choice of
>   cost-complexity tradeoff.

This means that it does not matter which criteria you use, the end result will be the same. Hence the graph with AIC instead of BIC will be similar, i.e. will convey the same information.

Comment: But how can it be the same, when BIC and AIC use different penalizations? This sentence that you posted makes no sense to me!

Comment: @MarkDollar, Although BIC and AIC use different penalizations, the function returns the best model when the number of parameters is fixed. If number of parameters is fixed then penalisation term is the same for all models considered, hence the best model is selected only depending on its log likelihood, which is the same for BIC and AIC.

Answer (score 0):

For a regsubsets-object we can plot a diagram to compare models with criterions: bic (default),  Cp, adjusted $R^2$ (adjr2) and $R^2$ (r2). Like this:

```
plot(regsubsets-object, scale="Cp")
```

So far as I know there no option for AIC. But the criterion Cp and AIC give us the same result/order. So there's no need for AIC. If you want to calculate AIC for a particular lm model use the function AIC like this:

```
AIC(lm.modell)
```